# Calculate the total number of participants and the total for slot 1, 2, 3

Tags: c#, function, loops, streamreader

so I've got this problem.
My text file has this layout:
Name of a person
Phone number
Time slot

I have to calculate the total number of participants of that file and the registered participants of slot 1,2,3 any help please?

e.g.:

```
 Manchester Event Information
 Total Registered Participants: 10
 Registered Participants for Slot 1:   6
 Registered Participants for Slot 2:   2
 Registered Participants for Slot 3:   2
 Participant 1 Name: Tom Jones
 Participant 2 Name: Katy Perry



static void displayRegisteredParticipants() 
{                    
    string sValidLocation;            
    int iIndex;            

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the location you wish to view data for.");
    sValidLocation = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (sValidLocation)
    {
        case "London":
            if (File.Exists("London.txt"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Location exists");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }  
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Location not found, please try again");
                sValidLocation = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine( "*  " + sValidLocation + " Event Information");
            Console.WriteLine();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("London.txt"))
            {

                string sReadName = sr.ReadLine();
                string sReadPhoneNo = sr.ReadLine();
                int iReadTimeSlot = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine()); 

            }
            break;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, I don't understand exactly what you need, a total of particpants ? because if I see your text, I see already the total ?

Comment: That is the output that I want to have, I need to calculate the total number of participants, the number of participants for slot 1, slot 2 and slot 3 and then create a loop to see the participants e.g. Participant 1 Name: Tom Jones

Comment: could you give the original file "London.txt", the source ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that but here's everything that I have in that file:
Tom Jones
07722990000
1
Katy Perry
01122334455
1
Kylie Jenner
01267483233
2
Taylor Swift
1234543234
3
Rod Stewart
07722996700
2
Liam Payne
07722995000
3
Harry Styles
07722994000
1
Jonas Blue
07722993000
1
Rita Ora
07722290000
1
Tom Walker
07722990010
1

Comment: the name is on one line then the phone number is under the name and the time slot (which can be 1 or 2 or 3) is under the phone number

Answer (score 0):

After you read your line out of the file you need to take a look at it and process it according to its contents:

```
string line = sr.ReadLine();

int tot = -1;
if(line.ToLower().StartsWith("total registered participants:"){
  line = line.ToLower().Replace("total registered participants:", "").Trim();
  int.TryParse(line, out tot);
}
else if(...)
```

Have a set of if that examine your lines and remove any non digits text, then parse what's left. Doing it this way allows your lines to come in any order and it tolerates case changes and extra spaces after the colon etc

Answer (score 0):

I think a little more info is required here. In the file you mention with name of person, phone number and time slot - how is the data formatted, for example is it comma separated? (I can't quite see how that maps to the sample data at the top of your code block)

As an aside - your code is going to get very long and include lots of repetition if you're planning on switching on every possible location / filename.. I'd recommend perhaps creating a new variable to hold your filename eg

```
var filename = $"{sValidLocation}.txt";
```

Then use that in your check for file existing and reading.

Comment: The thing is I am new in C# programming, there's no commas inside the file, it looks like this:
Alex Atkinson
07438058867
1
The only "skills" that I know are while, for, if, streamreader, streamwriter and i have to use these in order to get that.

Comment: Right sorry I think I see now. So the text at the top of your code block is the desired output, having read your data file in and processed it?
So, the streamreader's ReadLine() will give you one line of the file (as shown in @caius answer above). Then you'll need to try and deconstruct that line of data to extract your name, phone number and timeslot.
Look into the available c# string functions to see if you can find a way to identify the parts of the string (line of data). For example you could start from the end of the line and work back, the first number is always the time slot etc

Comment: Yes, the top bit is the output I want to have, but I really can't get my head around this, can you give me some more hints please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

```
void Main()
{
    //Input:
    //Tom Jones 07722990000 1
    //Katy Perry 01122334455 1
    //Kylie Jenner 01267483233 2
    //Taylor Swift 1234543234 3
    //Rod Stewart 07722996700 2
    //Liam Payne 07722995000 3
    //Harry Styles 07722994000 1
    //Jonas Blue 07722993000 1
    //Rita Ora 07722290000 1
    //Tom Walker 07722990010 1

    //This is the source file (input)
    string fileName = @"C:\\TEMP\\London.txt";
    //This is the output file that I want to create
    string outputFileName = @"C:\\TEMP\\output.txt";
    //I try now to cut the text files in parts and fill in objects
    List<Participant> list = GetParticipants(fileName);
    //I have now a list of clean object with all information
    //Now I create the output text file with new information
    CreateOutput(list, outputFileName);

    // This is the Output file:
    //  Total Registered Participants: 10
    //  Registered Participants for Slot 1: 6
    //  Registered Participants for Slot 2: 2
    //  Registered Participants for Slot 3: 2
    //  Participant 1 Name: Tom Jones
    //  Participant 2 Name: Katy Perry
    //  Participant 3 Name: Kylie Jenner
    //  Participant 4 Name: Taylor Swift
    //  Participant 5 Name: Rod Stewart
    //  Participant 6 Name: Liam Payne
    //  Participant 7 Name: Harry Styles
    //  Participant 8 Name: Jonas Blue
    //  Participant 9 Name: Rita Ora
    //  Participant 10 Name: Tom Walker
}

private void CreateOutput(List<Participant> list, string outputFileName)
{
    //I create the new output file here
    using(StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(outputFileName))
    {
        //I know in my collection total of participants, here 10
        w.WriteLine($"Total Registered Participants: {list.Count}");
        //For each slot I make a linq query, and I have a result for slot 1
        w.WriteLine($"Registered Participants for Slot 1: {list.Count(x => x.Slot == 1)}");
        //same for slot 2
        w.WriteLine($"Registered Participants for Slot 2: {list.Count(x => x.Slot == 2)}");
        //same for slot 3
        w.WriteLine($"Registered Participants for Slot 3: {list.Count(x => x.Slot == 3)}");

        int i=1;
        //for each participant in my collection, I write the name
        foreach(Participant p in list)
        {
            w.WriteLine($"Participant {i} Name: {p.Name}");
            i++;
        }
    }
}

private List<Participant> GetParticipants(string fileName)
{
    //I create an empty collection of object Participant (see class under)
    List<Participant> list = new List<UserQuery.Participant>();
    //I check if the input file exists
    if(File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        //This is the Regex pattern, maybe it's too difficult for you
        //but in clear, I take in each line three part of the text
        string pattern = @"(.*?)([\d]+)\s+([\d]+)";
        //This is used for later to test if the value in the string is an integer
        int outValue;
        //I open the input file
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            //I read each line to the end, Peek not consume the reading file
            while(reader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                //I read each line
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                //By Regurlar Expression, I take in each line the parts of text
                Match m = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                //I test if the regex is success and if I have more than three parts
                if(m.Success && m.Groups.Count > 2)
                {
                    //I create now each Participant object and I fill each part inside
                    Participant p = new Participant();
                    p.Name = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    p.Phone = m.Groups[2].Value;
                    //I test here if we don't have a null value or something other than an integer
                    if(int.TryParse(m.Groups[3].Value, out outValue))
                        p.Slot = outValue;
                    //I add each object in my Collection
                    list.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

//This is the class object for Participant
public class Participant
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    public int Slot {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: That looks good, but the only problem is that I never used some of the command and I'm a beginner in C# and I'm supposed to do all of this using only while, for loops and streamreaders and streamwriters. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: There is no simple other way to do this, use just with streamreader or streamwriter, it's not possible, but please, read my code, it works, I tested, try to understand and increase your knowledge. To Explain my code, I will put comments for you, please wait few minutes, I edit my post